# Finding probability of the given joint pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am given following joint pdf:

$$    f(x,y)=\frac{2}{3}(x+2y) $$  $$0\leq  x \leq1,  0\leq  y \leq1   $$

Now I need to  find the $P[X\leq0.5,Y\leq0.8]$.

My question is that will I double integrate the expression from 0 till respective limits like this:

$$          \int_{0}^{0.8}\int_{0}^{0.5} \frac{2}{3}(x+2y) \,dx\,dy   $$

Comment: Yes, that is okay.

Comment: There is no confusion.

For any $a,b\in(0,1)$, 

\begin{align}
P(X\le a, Y\le b)&=E\left[\mathbf1_{X\le a,Y\le b}\right]
\\&=\iint \mathbf1_{x\le a,y\le b }\,f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
\\&=\frac{2}{3}\iint\mathbf1_{x\le a,y\le b }(x+2y)\mathbf1_{0<x<1,0<y<1}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
\\&=\frac{2}{3}\int_0^b \int_0^a (x+2y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
\end{align}